# Prevent row from being inserted with a trigger

Tags: oracle, trigger

I'm trying to prevent a row being inserted if a certain condition is met using a trigger. I'm using a user defined exception to do this, however the row is still being inserted, despite the exception being thrown. I'm not sure why this is happening, I though when an exception was raised the transaction was rolled back and nothing would be inserted. The code is below.

```
create or replace TRIGGER 
  CHECK_OPTION
BEFORE INSERT 
ON lot_options  
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
    v_allowed_stage NUMBER;
    v_actual_completion_date DATE;
    option_change_invalid EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Starting the begin');
    SELECT stage_stage INTO v_allowed_stage
    FROM "TEAM3"."Option" o
    WHERE o.option_number = :new.option_number;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_allowed_stage);

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('Stage in a cell');

    SELECT actual_completion INTO v_actual_completion_date
    FROM progress
    WHERE stage_stage = v_allowed_stage
    AND Lot_lot_number = :new.lot_lot_number;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('completion date in storage');


    IF (v_actual_completion_date IS NOT NULL)
    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('condition holds true')
    THEN RAISE option_change_invalid;
    END IF;

    EXCEPTION
    WHEN option_change_invalid THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Invalid Option Change: Option change is not allowed in this stage of progress.');
END;
```

Comment: oracle version please and actual output should be logged to a table so we can see what happens on an insert.  Or do you have the output from an insert?

Comment: You're catching exception in `EXCEPTION` block, so nothing is rolled back. You need either to re-throw it or deliver error through `raise_application_error`

Comment: You should just remove the EXCEPTION SECTION and instead of declaring an exception and raising it use this instead and don't handle the error.

"raise_application_error( -20001, 
'Invalid Option Change: Option change is not allowed in this stage of progress.');"

Comment: Re raising it or throwing an application error both worked. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Exception block so you no longer catch the error.  Then the error will propagate out and prevent **and** prevent the insertion from occurring.